# what is the value of Chebyshev function at non-integer value?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

What is the value of Chebyshev $\psi(x)$ function at non-integer values ?

For example, what is the value of $\psi(3.56)$? I have seen,  in same place, it seems that $$\psi(3.56)=\psi(3)$$

And in some other place, $$\psi(3.56)=0$$ and $\psi(x)$ always equals to $0$ at non-integers.

The reasons why I need the values of Chebyshev at non-integer, because 
I need do some Fourier transform with this function.

Answer (score 4):

By definition $$\psi\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda\left(n\right)
 $$ where $$\Lambda\left(n\right)=\begin{cases}
\log\left(p\right), & n=p^{k},\,p\textrm{ is a prime and }k\geq1\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$ then $$\psi\left(3.56\right)=\sum_{n\leq3.56}\Lambda\left(n\right)=\sum_{n\leq3}\Lambda\left(n\right)=\psi\left(3\right)=\log\left(6\right).$$ Maybe there are some text that define $\psi(x)$ only for integers, but I always see the definition I used.